# Strange icon issue in Android Studio

Tags: android, icons

So, I have developed the first build of my own android flashlight application and I want to distribute it, but the problem is following;

I have created appropriate icon for the application and they all are scaled in the right way too using romannurik.github.io, the icons have been placed, I assume, in the correct way - I browsed to the project directory and replaced all sample icons (stock icons) with my own icons. Now, I have tried rebuilding and cleaning the project, yet nothing helps it.

In Android Studio, under mipmap folder, all icons are located, here is how the folder including pictures looks like

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Fmlp.png]

And by clicking on those .png's, I see the icon the application should have, but after I launch it on my phone, it still has the stock icon. Even setting build type to release, it still does the same. I also tried to relaunch the Android Studio and still nothing does it.

Some help? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The icon is setted in the AndroidManifest.

```
<application
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
```

Are you sure that you do not have this?

```
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
```

---

#### UPDATE

As you can see from the comments on this post, the user has a malformerd AndroidManifest [screenshot manifest](http://prntscr.com/9j5kk0)

There is a nested application tag with ther android icon property.

Comment: I do not have @drawable/ic_launcher

Comment: All icons of my application are located under mipmap folder, so in the manifest, it's @mipmap

Comment: <application android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/> is the line I put between application tags

Comment: have you imported other libs?

Comment: Can you please explain?

Comment: if you have imported other lib, and that lib have an icon setted in their manifest, this icon override yours..so in your manifest you have to override the icon by placing <application tools:replace="android:icon"...

Comment: No, the project is written all by myself and I have not imported other libraries

Comment: Here's my entire AndroidManifest.xml in this picture. As you can see, the application t ags are marked, I don't know why, but where the icon assigning line is, there is an icon itself on the left side, meaning it recognizes it, but at the same time, the line is marked. I don't know why. Here's the picture - http://prntscr.com/9j5kk0

Comment: Thanks for your support, I didn't read your last comment and I solved it anyway before you even posted it. I just rewrote the manifest file and it's working like a charm now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should set application icon in your manifest